# Find the sum $ \sum_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1 + (x + n)^2} $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, fourier-series, parametrization

More general problem than this
$$\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+n^2}$$
I've seen some cases where it was solved by calculating
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{a^2+n^2}$$
[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/736947/1149265)
or using the Fourier series of $e^x \, x \in [-\pi, \pi]$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1714944/1149265)

But I have never seen this problem generalized to my case
$$ \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \frac{1}{1 + (x + n)^2} $$

Is it possible to use the same methods here or it seems to be something new?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Closed form for $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{(z+n)^2+a^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/608059/closed-form-for-sum-n-infty-infty-frac1zn2a2) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bn%3D-%5Cinfty%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B1%2B(x%2Bn)%5E2%7D%24&p=1). There are also other at least very similar questions, e.g., [Can we give a closed form expression for $\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\frac1{a+(k+x)^2}$?](/q/3450077) (which has a restriction that $x\in(-1,1)$), etc.